# Adding arbitrary extra attribute to numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, python-class

With a 'normal' Python class I'm used to being able to arbitrarily add extra attributes. For example, I could do the following:

```py
# Create a class
class MyClass: pass

# Create an object of this class
my_object = MyClass()

# Add any attribute I want
my_object.my_new_attribute = "Hello world!"

# Now it has this attribute and I can use it:
print(my_object.my_new_attribute)
```

This runs without errors and prints `Hello world!`

However, I seem to be unable to do so with a `numpy.ndarray`. Consider the following:

```py
# Create an object of the ndarray class:
import numpy as np

my_object = np.array([1,2,3])

# Verify it is indeed of the `numpy.ndarray` type:
print(type(my_object))

# Add a new atribute
my_object.my_new_attribute = "Hello world!"
```

This outputs `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`, verifying we do indeed have an object of some class, but then when trying to add a new attribute we get an error: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'my_new_attribute'`

Why is this? I understand the error in the sense that `numpy.ndarray` indeed has no such attribute, but neither did `MyClass` in the first example and that didn't keep me from being able to just add it.

Comment: `vars(MyClass())` gives `{}`.  `vars(np.array([1,2,3]))` gives an error, about a missing `__dict__` artribute.  `ndarray` is defined in compiled code with a custom `__new__`.  It doesn't have a `__dict__` that can hold user defined attributes.  A list has the issue - no `__dict__`.

Comment: See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947072/534674 for why, in general, some classes do not have a `__dict__` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit the `np.ndarray` object and add attributes through the `__new__` method. There is a section in the docs on [adding an extra attribute to ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.subclassing.html#simple-example-adding-an-extra-attribute-to-ndarray).

Comment: I guess that's what I'll have to do. It leaves me wondering why I have to jump through this hoop though.